# How to profile all processes of the same name?

Tags: performance, profiling, perf

I'm profiling an application which spawns and kills an arbitrary number of processes, all having the same name. This means it's not enough to do something like `perf record -p <inital-pid>`, because the process with `PID=<inital-pid>` will be eventually terminated. The same binary is spawned again, but will have a different PID (whp). There may be two or more such processes running concurrently.

What I would like to do is record profiling data for all processes of a certain name, ideally with one command. Or, if there is some way to merge perf sample data easily, I would also be able to run perf on each spawned process. If there's another profiling tool besides perf which does this, I'd also be fine using that instead (as long as it has a decent method of reviewing results). Thanks for any help or insight!

Comment: Can you tweak your application to spawn `perf stat ...` instead of `...`?  I don't think `perf stat` or `perf record` *has* a follow-fork mode like `strace -f`.  I guess you could record everything system-wide and break it down by process later, though.  (But that wouldn't give separate total counts for each process for `perf stat report`)

Comment: Do you mean all these arbitrary processes, that get spawned and killed, are the child-processes of the application you are doing a profiling on ?

Comment: @PeterCordes I have been thinking about doing a system-wide sampling, because it might actually be a more useful metric. I am able to modify the application to spawn perf, but there is still the issue of merging many perf results.

Comment: @ArnabjyotiKalita I am profiling the child-processes, not the application which spawns them. I could try profiling that application, since from what I understand perf will also handle child-processes.

Comment: If you want to merge counts between processes, IMO don't record them separately in the first place.  System-wide is simple to do.